# Is it possible to overlay a 2D image over a pointcloud in RViz2

Tags: ros, 2d-image, overlay, ros-crystal, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I have a 2D image, taken from a video. Let's say I also have a Pointcloud, generated by a radar sensor. Would it be possible to project this 2D image over the Pointcloud, such that the Pointcloud acts like a 3D model (in which the points are vertices of said model) and the image acts as the texture for the model? If it is possible, is there anything online that could tell me how to do it?

EDIT: I also saw a question (https://answers.ros.org/question/218502/rviz-display-image-in-3d-scene/) and the top answer said something about being able to use an image to texture a Mesh object. Would it be possible to use the radar information I used to create a Pointcloud in order to create a Mesh? The radar data is represented as polar coordinates, which we then convert to cartesian to generate the Pointcloud)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321701/is-it-possible-to-overlay-a-2d-image-over-a-pointcloud-in-rviz2/) by [NN_SS](https://answers.ros.org/users/41003/nn_ss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to try to project a RGB video onto the point cloud, I used to do that with asus xtion which was providing a point cloud and rgb image stream. I was able to visualize video on the point cloud by adding Camera and choosing "Image Rendering" as overlay while also visualizing point cloud. If you dont have a video stream and you want to project a constant image, you can convert your image to sensor_msgs/Image as in [here](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages), then do the same thing. Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [ozzdemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/31442/ozzdemir/) with karma: 28 on 2019-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NN_SS](https://answers.ros.org/users/41003/nn_ss/) on 2019-04-23**:
This sounds like what I want to do (I have a video stream and a set of radar data that is synced with the video) do you mind taking me through more specific steps, I'm kind of new to ROS/RViz.

Thank you so much for the quick response!

**Comment by [ozzdemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/31442/ozzdemir/) on 2019-04-23**:
[This](https://pasteboard.co/IbuHIf9.png) is the configuration I was using, but its been a long time. I can't test it now since I don't have the hardware now but if you still need help and can share a bag file, I may check via it.

**Comment by [NN_SS](https://answers.ros.org/users/41003/nn_ss/) on 2019-04-23**:
I think I got it, thanks so much for the help!

**Comment by [ozzdemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/31442/ozzdemir/) on 2019-04-23**:
You are welcome, don't forget to accept as answer.

**Comment by [akashbaskaran](https://answers.ros.org/users/112931/akashbaskaran/) on 2022-08-05**:
The link seems to be broken. Is there any other link for it?
I am facing a similar issue.  I have a camera image selected to overlay and a lidar pointcloud. They seem to be in 2 different windows. How do i combine them?